# How to consume SOAP based web service in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco

I have a requirement to consume soap web service in alfresco and render the data on dashlet, so i requesting you all please share if you any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One alternative would be to write a java backed webscript in Alfresco Share and let this webscript consume the SOAP webservice and then output the result to your dashlet. (I am assuming the SOAP webservice you want to consume is not one provided by Alfresco)

Comment: Thank you very much for the valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (in addition to a java-backed webscript like @billerby said) is to create a service and add it to Alfresco's service registry. If you expose that service as a root-scoped object, you might use it in javascript-backed webscripts, too. And if you make the service with nicely parametrised methods and all, you could reuse it on different SOAP calls without recompiling for each small change, but just changing the js webscript controller.

Comment: Hi, I am new to the Alfresco.Can you please elabarate it step by step or please share if you have any example.                         Thank you.

Comment: Well, its a too wide a question, there would be 1,000,000 steps :)
But you might start with reading how to develop an alfresco module: http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Developing_an_Alfresco_Module Then you can come back and ask more specific questions, about how to do SOAP in a Java module, or in example how to connect those to alfresco Java API. Or something like how to place this service in alfresco javascript services api. Like I said, you can't really give efficient steps on questions of type "how do I build a blue train", you have to be a bit more specific.